# Nokogiri gem failing to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install nokogiri v 1.6.7.2 in a new rails project. I'm running Kali Linux (debian-based). Here is the stack trace:

```
    $ gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.7.2' -- --use-system-libraries
Building native extensions with: '--use-system-libraries'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.2 -r ./siteconf20160405-3609-rdkvif.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.2
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-exslt-dir
    --without-exslt-dir
    --with-exslt-include
    --without-exslt-include=${exslt-dir}/include
    --with-exslt-lib
    --without-exslt-lib=${exslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libexslt-config
    --without-libexslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

I've checked I have libxml2 installed:

```
apt-get install libxml2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxml2 is already the newest version (2.9.3+dfsg1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And I saw in other threads to try using the --use-sytem-libraries flag, but that still causes the same error. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: did u try `sudo gem install nokogiri` ?

Comment: **DO NOT USE SUDO**  Try reading the debian install tips here: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#ubuntu___debian.  Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: Nokogiri already installed if you use Rails (check Gemfile.lock)

Comment: Have you tried without the --use-system-libraries?

Comment: Since you're using a debian-based distro, I would recommend going through the [install tutorial](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) from Nokogiri. It has a troubleshooting section on missing development header files. Hope that helps, or at least rules out another possibility :]

Comment: I've tried with and without --use-system-libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `libxml2` and `libxslt`, you also require some additional development libraries. Install them using `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev`. More at https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri.org-tutorials/blob/master/content/installing_nokogiri.md.